# How to add an admin internal action to a page link

Tags: magento2, action

I'm new to Magento, but I've set up some controllers and phtml files that are working.

However, I have a phtml file containing a link:

```
<i>Do you already have an account?</i>
<a href="mycompany/dashboard">Connect Account?</a>
```

The "mycompany/dashboard" url fires the respective controller elsewhere on the site, but the link doesn't work in this phtml file. Why?

Comment: This link will reach to an admin page?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do. However I didn't realize I needed a key in the admin url. That's what the getUrl() function provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the full URL path, like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('mycompany/dashboard') ?>">Connect Account?</a>
```

This assumes that your block class extends `AbstractBlock`.